# Change the height of layout in master page when dynamically add a control in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, user-controls, dynamic-data

![enter image description here][1]How can I change the height of the layout of the my page when the user adds new controllers. I would like to enhance the height of my page when the user adds a new control.

I am using in master page

```
<div class="main">
     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

and in my css

```
.main
{
    padding: 0px 12px;
    margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
    height: auto; 
}
```

One more question, can I achieve that programmatically in aspx.cs file ?

Any advice would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. Surely the div, when height is set to auto, will grow and shrink according to the height of the content within it? The browser should handle this for you. You should not need to set it manually?

Comment: i tried div however it doesn't work

Comment: do you have any elements at a higher level than your div that are fixed height? - Also how are you testing? Are you using anything like IE's Dev Toolbar, FireFox's FireBug or Chrome's Dev Toolbar?

Comment: no i don't have. I am using user controls..actually I am adding dynamically a new Panel which includes labels and textboxes by clicking a button , however the height does not change.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your asp:Content has elements's in that have content in or a set height it should add to the height of the page

example

> `<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">`
>   `<div>`
>
> `</div>`
>   `</asp:Content>`

Also need to check for CSS styles that are altering the height of div's as this will effect any content you place in there

Comment: is this working properly when I add controls dynamically from aspx.cs file ?

Comment: It should. You can wrap the ContentPlaceHolder with the div and it should expand

Comment: i wrapped it, when I insert a new textbox from aspx it is expanded correctly, however when I am trying to add controllers dynamically from aspx.cs like Panel1.Controls.Add(table); it doesn't expand, any ideas please?

Comment: i mean that the dynamically created new controllers are outside of the border of ContentPlaceHolder

Comment: so like this <asp:ContentPlaceHolder></asp:ContentPlaceHolder> <new control> ?

Comment: e.g. if the user adds several Panels on the interface then, some of them at the bottom of the page are outside of the height of my page.

Comment: if your adding panels you could set a value of the height propertie on the panel.

Comment: i dont have a problem with the panel's height...you can see the picture that I uploaded on my initial post

Comment: when the user adds a new contact the panel is expanded respectively, however the whole page is not expanded.

Comment: Do the panels have any styling on them ?

Comment: I "fixed" this problem by using hidden values instead of dynamic addition of the new panels with all this implies...